# CakePHP - Call to undefined function find()

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to call the `find()` function of a loaded model and I get the following error: **Call to undefined function find()**

If I can call `create()` and `save()`, why is `find()` undefined?

```
public function admin_upload() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->loadModel('TempImage');

        $uploadedFileName = $_FILES['data']['name']['Staticpage']['main_image'];
        $uploadedType = $_FILES['data']['type']['Staticpage']['main_image'];
        $uploadedTmpFileName = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name']['Staticpage']['main_image'];
        $uploadedError = $_FILES['data']['error']['Staticpage']['main_image'];
        $uploadedSize = $_FILES['data']['size']['Staticpage']['main_image'];

        $this->TempImage->create();

        $imageData = array(
            'name' => $uploadedFileName,
            'type' => $uploadedType,
            'tmp_name' => $uploadedTmpFileName,
            'error' => $uploadedError,
            'size' => $uploadedSize
        );

        $temporaryData = array(
            'path' => $imageData
        );

        $this->TempImage->save($temporaryData);

        $lastTempImageThumbPath = $this->TempImage-find(
                'first',
                array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'id' => $this->TempImage->getLastInsertID()
                    )
                )
        );
        $this->set('thumb', $lastTempImageThumbPath['TempImage']['thumb_path']);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a small fault, you're missing the `>`

Wrong: `$this->TempImage-find(`

Right: `$this->TempImage->find(`

**Comment from Brian Warshaw:**
Just to add a little clarity so you understand, when that > was missing, PHP was interpreting as you trying to subtract the results of the undefined function find from the value of $this->TempImage

Comment: No problem! Had the same problem once. After knowing, you check that first.

Comment: @felipe.zkn Just to add a little clarity so you understand, when that `>` was missing, PHP was interpreting as you trying to subtract the results of the undefined function `find` from the value of `$this->TempImage`